# mongoDB Map/Reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, nosql

I am trying to figure out this map/reduce system in mongoDB.  I have the following basic schema/layout in my collection.

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: n1,
    website: w1,
    tags: [
        myTag1,
        myTag3
    ]
}

{
    _id: 2,
    name: n2,
    website: w2,
    tags: [
        myTag2,
        myTag3
    ]
}

{
    _id: 3,
    name: n3,
    website: w3,
    tags: [
        myTag2,
        myTag4
    ]
}
```

How can I retrieve an array of unique tags?  I would like this to be returned to me for further use.

```
{
    tags: [
        myTag1,
        myTag2,
        myTag3,
        myTag4
    ]
}
```

By the way this is what I have come up with, but it just returns the _id and tags of each item instead of combining the tags into a single object.

```
var map = function() {emit( this._id,{tags: this.tags});};

var reduce = function(key, values) {
    var t = [];

    values.forEach(function(doc) {
        var tags = doc.tags;
        tags.forEach(function(tag) {
            if (!(tag in t)) {
                t.push(tag);
            }
        });
    });

    return {tags: t};
};

var op = db.businesses.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: "mr_results"});

db[op.result].find();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use map-reduce in your case. Just use the `distinct` function:

```
db.businesses.distinct('tags')
```

You can try it in the mongo shell:

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.businesses.insert({tags: ['tag1', 'tag2']})
> db.businesses.insert({tags: ['tag3', 'tag4']})
> db.businesses.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fa05b2b036495bf4ac9c0cc"), "tags" : [ "tag1", "tag2" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fa05b33036495bf4ac9c0cd"), "tags" : [ "tag3", "tag4" ] }

> db.businesses.distinct('tags')
[ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4" ]
```

Also, you should keep in mind that map/reduce in MongoDB is not suitable for real-time querying.

Comment: That results in 
`[
 [
        myTag1,
        myTag3
    ],
 [
        myTag2,
        myTag3
    ],
 [
        myTag2,
        myTag4
    ]
]`

I need 
`[
 [
        myTag1,
        myTag2,
  myTag3,
  myTag4
    ]
]`

Comment: Hmm, strange. I posted an update with an example from the mongo shell, maybe that helps.

Comment: That is VERY strange, mine doesn't do what that example shows at all

Comment: Which version of MongoDB do you use?

Comment: I just copy/pasted each line in that example and my result is `[ [ "tag1", "tag2" ], [ "tag3", "tag4" ] ]`

Comment: That's a very old version (probably 2-3 releases cycles behind). Unless you're forced to use 1.4.4 I strongly suggest you upgrade to the newest version (which should fix the problem).

Comment: The biggest problem is I use debian and the apt-get install fails I had to build install it myself.  I am going to try to see what I can do about getting it updated.  Thanks.

Comment: I got 2.0.4 installed and it works beautifully, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Using [MongoDB MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) you could do it as follows:

```javascript
function m() {
  this.tags.forEach(function(x) { emit('tag', x); });
}
function r(k, v) {
  var res = {};
  v.forEach(function(x) { res[x] = true; });
  return res;
}
db.businesses.mapReduce(m, r, {out:'out'});
// Now the 'out' collection has a record whose "value" property
// has a key for each of the tags in the source collection.
function getTags(coll) {
  var tags=[], o=db[coll].find()[0].value;
  for (var i in o) { tags.push(i) }
  return tags; // Same as Object.keys(db[coll].find()[0].value)
}
listTags('out'); // => ['myTag1', 'myTag2', 'myTag3', 'myTag4']
```